# Error on Install DiskStation Manager (DSM) with Synology, forward port 23

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, nas

I just got this error when trying to install my new Synology DS920+ on my local network:

> An error occurred during installation. The telnet service of Synology NAS is turned on for error determination. Please configure your router to forward port 23 to Synology NAS, and then contact Synology online support.

How do I configure my (AT&T) router to allow for forwarding port 23 to Synology NAS? I don't know anything about how to use my router other than I have managed to get internet through it, so be gentle.

There is also an option to [install the DS920+ software manually](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download/DS920+#system), maybe I can do that instead.

[image]

Comment: that does not sound safe. Contact support first, to see if they really want you to do this, and can explain why they want you to.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not safe so I know?

Comment: Telnet isn't a secure service, so in the modern era, its not generally used outside the LAN environment. instead secure protocols like SSH which support strong encryption and authentication schemes are typically used for exposing shell access over the WAN. By Forwarding the port, you are allowing anyone in the world to connect to your NAS over telnet. There are people out there that scan the whole internet looking for open ports to common services like telnet. I'd guess you'd have only minutes before someone noticed you had opened that port.

Comment: Why would synology be asking for this, I thought they were a respectable brand...

Comment: they are, and it may be because the system is running with minimal functionality do to the failed install. Just contact them before doing anything

Comment: if you have a working DSM installed, and you are just trying to install an upgrade, I'd wait a couple days and try again. Also, if you aren't connecting your NAS to the Internet for remote access, it may be that the upgrades aren't particularly important for you anyway.

Comment: I wasn't able to get a working DSM installed yet :/

Comment: so what software are you running here? My Synology devices are all older than yours, but they came with DSM pre-installed on the device. The screen you are showing appears to be part of DSM, so thats why I'm asking.

Comment: I am trying to install [DSM 7.0](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download/DS920+#system). It didn't come preinstalled.

Comment: so I'm not entirely certian what your initial state or level of experience are, but what URL did you go to to get to where you are at? what happens if you point a browser to your nas at port 5000 or 5001 (https)? the download link you posted shows that you can upgrade from 6.2.3 or 6.2.4 to 7.0, but you have to indicate the version you are coming from.

Comment: I don't have any experience with networking / NAS, this is my first system. I went to [find.synology.com](http://find.synology.com/), where it searches for devices on the local network. Then I click connect, it redirects me to http://<myip>:5000 (not https). And tries to install something. That's pretty much all I know, I've tried installing 6.2.4 and it said I need to install 7.0, so I tried that, it gets to 99%, then counts down for 10 minutes saying it is restarting, then boom after 10 minutes it says "sorry there was an error" basically. I've tried 5 or 6 times.

Comment: I pressed the factory reset button as well, as per the customer support person on the phone. I filed a ticket to talk to a DSM specialist 2 days ago but haven't heard from them since yet. Actually find.synology.com says DSM version is 7.0-41890 on the DS920+ device. Maybe that is useful? Status "Migratable". Click "connect", accept the terms, then it starts "Loading...".

Comment: After 5-10 minutes of loading, it responded with "We've detected that you had moved the hard drives from DiskStation to DS920+. You can migrate your data and settings to your new Synology NAS now.". I don't really know what that means, all did was put one brand new hard drive into one of the 4 slots on the NAS, that's it. The button now says "migrate", but I already tried that a bunch of times and it hasn't worked. I click migrate and it takes me to "Install the DiskStation Manager".

Comment: I selected upload a local pat file (DSM_DS920+_41890.pat), and it starts the percentage upload gauge. I tried doing it from the internet and that didnt work either, but I figure the pat is probably more bulletproof than the internet connection version.

Comment: Again it failed now, saying "Failed to upload the DSM installation file. Please check the network connection and try again." It got about 50% the way through. My internet occasionally cuts out, maybe once a week for a minute, but not every 10 minutes.

Comment: Finally tried it again, and it said the usual, "Something went wrong. Please click the button below to try reconnecting to your Synology NAS." I will probably just return this thing, it seems to be broken, unless maybe I just didn't plugin the hard drive into it properly or something.

Comment: I wonder if you got a refurb or used device? If there isn't a disk in the first slot, make sure you populate it, but other than that, it does seem like somthing is wrong with that unit. Try getting it replaced, and see if you have problems with the new one. may be a lemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I got a hard drive that was not on the [supported hard drive list](https://www.synology.com/en-us/compatibility?search_by=products&model=DS920%2B&category=hdds_no_ssd_trim&p=1&change_log_p=1). I returned what I got and got one from the list and it works!

*Amazon recommended a specific drive next to the product, so I got that... Didn't work! Lesson learned.*