# How to connect to synology NAS through terminal

Tags: hard-drive, ssh, terminal, nas

*I [figured out](https://superuser.com/questions/1671086/error-on-install-diskstation-manager-dsm-with-synology-forward-port-23) that my external hard drive I used for the NAS was not supported, so I got a supported one and it works!*

Now I am here:

[image]

How do I `cd /Volumes/MyNAS` or `ssh MyNAS` so I can start uploading data from my other `/Volumes/MyPassport 1` harddrives onto the NAS, and start using data? What is the proper workflow and configuration?

I have tried to `ssh <ip>` to the IP address shown in the browser window with the password I just defined during setup, but it says permission denied. (I pasted the password into SSH, not typed, if that matters).

[image]

Where do I find the IP I should be ssh-ing into? Or is there a way to just directly CD into it? Do I want to enable FTP SSH or rsync or anything like that?

The goal would be to use the files like I would on my laptop: I want to stream some gzipped JSON currently to parse it (wikidump, 90+GB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the network configuration you look for the IP
2. In the Terminal and SNMP section you enable the ssh and choose a port
3. The syntax to connect is: ssh user@host -p port

*the port is the port you choose in configuration
**use the builtin admin or another "Administrator Member"